# after update from 12.04 to 14.01 touch pad is not working

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, software-installation, laptop, touchpad

after updating to 14.01 version my touch pad is not working. im using hp pavilion 17. my laptop is brand new, it came with 12.04 pre-installed ubuntu version.
my wired usb mouse do work but the right click on it does not work. moreover, when i scroll up or down using wheel button on mouse the mose functions stop at all, then i have to enable mouse again from the terminal.
since i am not that much tech savvy and also new to ubuntu kindly help me.

Comment: Same here, with Apple Bluetooth Touchpad. After that upgrade it started disconnecting when I touch it with more than one finger. 15.04, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect if you have some library problems by opening the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>) and typing:

```
sudo apt-get check
```

If you get an error message (if not see the link below), you can solve it using:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This will repair broken dependencies, that could be the problem.

If this doesn't solve the issue, you could try this solution (it requires more work):

[Keyboard and touchpad stopped working after sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576702/keyboard-and-touchpad-stopped-working-after-sleep/576707?noredirect=1#comment796835_576707)

Hope you can solve it!