# Keyboard and touchpad stopped working after sleep

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, touchpad, suspend, 14.10

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 but I had this problem before with Ubuntu 14.04.

I need to force my computer to shut don't, else it does not respond.

What can I do to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried?

`$ sudo apt-get check`

If you have some library problems, that command will tell you.
In that case, you can solve it using:

`$ sudo apt-get -f install`

This will repair broken dependencies, that could be the problem.

Comment: The output of sudo apt-get check:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

Comment: @RitaMartins, if you don't get an error message is because you don't have any issues with libraries.
You could the `dpkg --configure -a` option used in this post:
[link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40457/keyboard-and-touch-pad-stopped-working-after-shutting-down-the-computer-while-it?rq=1)
Hope that helps!